# min and max value in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to know how to find the minimum and maximum value in excel sheets using criteria? I try to use this formula but it's not working. I need specific text if is match it will show minimum or maximum value. For your information, I am using Excel 2013.

[image]

Comment: Resume your data with Pivot Tables, and then filter max and min values for each name.

Answer (score 2):

I believe using a pivot table would be simplest, but that said, you can use the following array formulae (Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
=MAX(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(D1,A2:A6)),MIN(B2:B6),B2:B6))
=MIN(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(D1,A2:A6)),MAX(B2:B6),B2:B6))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Like

```
=MAX(IF(IFERROR(FIND("Shoaib",$A$2:$A$6),0)>0,$B$2:$B$6))
```

And

```
=MIN(IF(IFERROR(FIND("Shoaib",$A$2:$A$6),0)>0,$B$2:$B$6))
```

Entered as array formulas with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

---

Data

[image: Data]

Answer (score 0):

For purposes of your reporting, one sensible option here would be to just add a filter on the `Name` column.  Then, just take the max and min of the entire `Marks` column.  This would let you quickly obtain the min or max marks for any person using only the Excel GUI.  And it avoids the need to edit a formula for each different name.

Answer (score 0):

Input these as `ARRAY` formula. Means press `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` after putting formula in cell.

```
=MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Shoaib",A2:A6)),B2:B6,""))

=MIN(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Shoaib",A2:A6)),B2:B6,""))
```

[image]